# How to add more value with existing value in text field by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code are working fine, but when I write on "#sub_id" field then remove all existing value on "#landing" field  but I can not remove, I need to add "#sub_id" after "#landing" value.

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<label for="p_url">landing page</label>
    <input type="text" id="landing" name="p_url" placeholder="Campaign Name"     value="www.example.com?" readonly>
    <label for="pi">Promotional Info</label>
    <input type="text" id="sub_id" name="pi" placeholder="sub_id">

</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sub_id").keyup(function(){
      $("#landing").val($("#sub_id").val());
  });

  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, can't understand your question, can you be a little more clear and maybe add a desired result example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
$("#landing").val($("#landing").val() + $("#sub_id").val());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working but when I remove some text by backspace on "#sub_id"  then "#landing" new value by "#sub_id" can not be remove. have any other solution?

Comment: You should perform the right validations before any operation. I mean, in this case, you should ask, for example, if the content of #sub_id is a number. Otherwise does not make sense to use it for operations. So first, check that #sub_id is a valid number before use it. For example: if $.isNumeric($("#sub_id").val()) { //then do the operation }